# Sending task to background and Bring it to foreground

Tags: android

I have this requirement to send my application background and then bring it to foreground on some key capture intents (not from application launcher offcourse) So How can I send the current tasks to background and bring the same to foreground  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use moveTaskToBack() to send the activity in the background and still running if the user presses the back key.
see :[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for the way on how to do this. its quite simple.

so in order to do this you will also need to override the onBackPressed() method or onKeyPressed() and call this method if the back button was pressed (dont forget to return true on the back pressed methods so android is aware that you consumed the event and doesnt finish the activity).

For returning to this activity that you have moved to the background you can post a notification with a pending intent to launch it back and that will automatically bring the activity to foreground.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To send you application to background you should call `moveTaskToBack()` from your Activity class. When your Activity gets new intent (btw. the `onNewIntent()` method from your Activity will be called) your Activity gets into foreground by system (you don't have to do anything).

Comment: Thanks Martin, My use case is something like this, user of my application will not find application icon in application list so he can not launch it. instead he will launch /bring application to foregorund by pressing some key combination. So I want to programatically do the work of launcher does. any help in this regard would be great

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "background?" Activities are stacked one upon another as you create new Activities, then accessed in reverse order using the device's back button. Think of the push() and pop() methods, it's the same paradigm. Applications that need to have code running non-interactively should extend android.app.Service, but beware that you can do some real damage implementing a service. Rogue processes can drain battery life and reduce UI responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

I solve all the problem pertaining to notification start with fresh activity after moveTaskToBack(true) when back key is pressed by

adding  to manifest  android:launchMode="SingleTask"    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"in the activity xml markup section